# Filter a chart directly in libreoffice calc

Tags: filter, charts, libreoffice-calc

I have a chart which shows the data I want when I filter for values > 0 on a single column. But I would like to have this filter inside of the chart itself so that I can look at the workbook with no filters, and still see the chart with the zero values filtered out.

[image]

So I want the first row to appear in the chart because the last value is > 0, but I want the chart to ignore the 2nd row because the last column value == 0

Is there some way to set a filter on the chart itself?